# Как сделать счет до определённого числа

Tags: python-3.x

Этот код - выведет от 20 до 2(напечатает end  и потом 1):

```
def start():
    n = 20
    while n > 0:
        print(n)
        n -= 1
        if n == 1:
            print("end")
```

Как сделать наоборот? Чтоб до 20 и "end"?

Comment: n = 1, а затем n += 1

Comment: добавить после while, а if n == 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как сделать наоборот вот этого

Ну непонятно же ничего...

**от `n` до 1**

---

```
for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    print(i)
print('end')


for i in reversed(range(1, n + 1)):
    print(i)
print('end')


while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n -= 1
print("end")
```

**от 1 до `n`**

---

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    print(i)
print('end')


i = 1
while i <= n:
    print(i)
    i += 1
print("end")
```